# How to generate random link for homepage for each user in wordpress and display the content only when clicking on the link?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have the following ability on a Wordpress page:

We have a homepage designed in WordPress, say http://www.examplesite.com.

I want this page to be seen only when clicked from a link, say, http://www.examplesite.com/?code=REF_35DHC4XQ&fbclid=IwAR3X5692MvS4A_wWRIz-qfEOzkvjjnJtSuGnAjaXY-rkF7iER9nTHbm9Bk0

Otherwise, the homepage should show the text "Sorry, this page is invitation only"

The link could be different for different people.

I mean code=REF_35DHC4XQ&fbclid=IwAR3X5692MvS4A_wWRIz-qfEOzkvjjnJtSuGnAjaXY-rkF7iER9nTHbm9Bk0 can be different as different people can be invited using different links.

So I would like to have the ability to create these links and see that home page only based on the random link.

I have searched on google about this but I could find plugins only to display the content based on a single link that can be set by the admin. But I want this link to be different for each user and should display the same homepage content for each user.

Is this possible to be set up in WordPress? If so, please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Were you able to do it? _I could find plugins only to display the content based on a single link that can be set by the admin_ Which ones?